how to navigate another screen in on tab using react native expo?
Currently, I'm creating a mobile app using react native expo.
My app has 2 tabs (Home and Explore) and I want it to navigate another screen in the same tab.
my project's file tree is like below
 ┣ (tabs)
 ┃ ┣ home
 ┃ ┃ ┣ detail.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┣ _layout.tsx
 ┃ ┗ explore.tsx
 ┣ +not-found.tsx
 ┗ _layout.tsx

I'd like to make detail.tsx and index.tsx one group(home tab) because I don't want to make detail tab.
And below are _layout.tsx files.
/app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { HapticTab } from '@/components/HapticTab';
import { IconSymbol } from '@/components/ui/IconSymbol';
import TabBarBackground from '@/components/ui/TabBarBackground';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarButton: HapticTab,
        tabBarBackground: TabBarBackground,
        tabBarStyle: Platform.select({
          ios: {
            position: 'absolute',
          },
          default: {},
        }),
      }}
    >
      {/* Home Tab */}
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <IconSymbol size={28} name="house.fill" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      
      {/* Explore Tab */}
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="explore"
        options={{
          title: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <IconSymbol size={28} name="paperplane.fill" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}

/app/_layout.tsx
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
      </Stack>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

But when I launch my app, it shows not found screen.
What's wrong?
I simply want it to shows home/index.tsx when I launch my app.
